# xargs not working on Linux

Tags: linux, xargs

I want to **run multiple python scripts with different arguments at once**.

In trying to do that, I came across this `xargs` command; I want to learn about it.

When trying this example command `echo {a..d} | xargs -n 1 -I % mv % %-01` it works on my MacBook and gives the desired output.

But after I login to a VPS running Ubuntu 16.04, and issue the same command I get this `mv: cannot stat 'a b c d': No such file or directory` I looked through the man page and googled around but couldn't find any reason.

ps: I guess xargs is the newest version from default Ubuntu repo.

(This is my very first question on SO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `echo` command generates a single line of space-delimited output:

```
$ echo {a..d}
a b c d
```

While normally `xargs` wants whitespace-delimited input,  **when using -I** it wants newline-delimited input. From the man page:

```
-I replace-str
      Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names
      read  from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate in‐
      put items; instead the separator is the newline character.  Implies -x
      and -L 1.
```

Your existing command line results in the following command:

```
mv a b c d a b c d-01
```

You need to split the output of your `echo` command into multiple lines:

```
$ echo {a..d} | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -n 1 -I % echo mv % %-01
mv a a-01
mv b b-01
mv c c-01
mv d d-01
```

You can, as you point out, replace the `tr ...` in the above with `xargs -n1`, which gives you the same result: because without `-I` xargs reads whitespace-delimited arguments, this results in echoing each argument on a separate line.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But if I remove the mv command and try `echo {a..d} | xargs -n 1` I get each letter in a separate line, but why it does not work with another command? Also it works with an extra pipe added like `echo {a..d} | xargs -n 1 | xargs  -I % mv % %-01` as reminded by a friend.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear to me. One thing, is there an extra 'echo' in the long command?

Comment: The `echo` command is there just to show the generated command lines. You would remove that.

Comment: Thanks so much, for the answer and for the edit, my bad English. I have accepted your answer.